# CSS - Limit element position by the parent height/width to prevent overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to prevent an absolute positioned element to overflow its parent container by limiting its position if it overflows the parent?

In my case: I have a round graph, with bubbles inside, I use `border-radius` to create the circle, and use `position:absolute` + `top` and `left` to position the element based on a calculation result.

I want to prevent this from happening:

[image: circle]

In this case, or in an extreme case like `top: 0; left: 0;` the bubble overflows the parent circle, and I want it to be contained within the circle limits.

Is it possible to do that? Or do I have to use javascript? If I have to use javascript: is it possible to obtain the limit of an element rounded with `border: radius: 100%`?

Comment: Tried position relative on the containing circle, if it doesn't work then you probably need to utilize some JavaScript

Comment: Can you add your code, ideally make a snippet / demo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but here's how `overflow: hidden` already has some built-in functionality for this. I'm using JavaScript to have the dot follow the cursor:

```js
$('.circle').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.dot').css({
    'top': e.clientY,
    'left': e.clientX
  });
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```